# Gaining the server side benefits of Async/Await without changing the service contract

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

Spent some time googling this but not finding a definitive answer and not sure how to prove it with a test (suggestions welcome).

We have a WCF service with a method that waits for a specific event to occur in a loop. In the loop it used Thread.Sleep to wait a few 100 ms which is a lot in a service (we want to redesign this. Not a good idea to sleep in a service right?).

I would like to improve the throughput by making the method async and using Task.Delay instead, without changing the service contract. After making the method async and regenerating the contract class, it does seem the contract signature is intact. I can also see that the generated code now has a statemachine which seems to indicate it is now async.

My question is if I will get the benefit of the thread being available for other work even if I call the async service method in a synchronous way? Will the framework await the service method?

Br

Comment: The caller of the method is a client to the service. It's not an internal call. So the framework handles the call of the method. I'm wondering if that will be done with an Await or not (thereby freeing the thread for other service calls when my code awaits something).

Comment: Tasks are not sent between server and client. So the server does not care care if the request is handled by the client with a task. All the server knows about the client is a request payload, and the fact it must send back a response payload.

Comment: Ok that seems reasonable. So the server side benefits of a method being async are disconnected from how the client is consuming the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if I will get the benefit of the thread being available for other work even if I call the async service method in a synchronous way?
>
> So the server side benefits of a method being async are disconnected from how the client is consuming the service?

Asynchrony is independent on the server side and the client side. Asynchrony on the server enables more scalability (which may or may not increase throughput). Asynchrony on the client enables UI responsiveness.

Network communication is a "divider" here, so either side can treat it asynchronously or synchronously, independent of the other application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. These is in line with my limited view of how it works.
Does this mean that the server will automatically Await any async method being 
called in the service?

Comment: Your code must have the `await` statements for the methods it calls itself. [If the entry point of your service implementation returns a `Task<T>`, then the WCF framework will `await` it internally](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the great explanation.

I just realised I missed making the method which has the OperationContract attribute return a Task. Guess I'm missing out inb the internal await now?

Comment: It's easiest to start with the lowest-level method, e.g., change `Thread.Sleep` to `await Task.Delay`. The compiler will guide you from there: change that method to `async` and use `await` everywhere it's called, etc. You will eventually end up at your service implementation methods.

Comment: Yes that how I did it actually. I just wasn't sure if the wcf framwork would await it. Thanks for the clarification.